# kivy AttributeError: 'Screen' object has no attribute 'to_window'

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Имеется такой код:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.button import Button


Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', True)
Config.write()


class Screen(App):
    def build(self):
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self._keyboard_closed, self)
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_up=self._on_keyboard_up)
        return Button(text='dg')

    def _keyboard_closed(self):
        self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
        self._keyboard = None

    def _on_keyboard_down(self, key, scancode=None, codepoint=None, modifier=None):
        print(scancode)

    def _on_keyboard_up(self, key, scancode=None, codepoint=None, modifier=None):
        print(scancode)

Screen().run()
```

при запуске выдаётся ошибка:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "D:/kivy_project/diger/create_bg.py", line 29, in <module>
     Screen().run()
   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 826, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 502, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.window.mainloop()
   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 727, in mainloop
     self._mainloop()
   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 460, in _mainloop
     EventLoop.idle()
   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 337, in idle
     Clock.tick()
   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\clock.py", line 581, in tick
     self._process_events()
   File "kivy\_clock.pyx", line 384, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
   File "kivy\_clock.pyx", line 414, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
   File "kivy\_clock.pyx", line 412, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
   File "kivy\_clock.pyx", line 167, in kivy._clock.ClockEvent.tick
   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 606, in _upd_kbd_height
     self._keyboard_changed = not self._keyboard_changed
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 483, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 524, in kivy.properties.Property.set
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 579, in kivy.properties.Property.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1214, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1120, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 1449, in kivy.properties.AliasProperty.trigger_change
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 1455, in kivy.properties.AliasProperty.trigger_change
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 579, in kivy.properties.Property.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1214, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1120, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 952, in <lambda>
     keyboard_height=lambda *dt: self.update_viewport())
   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1418, in update_viewport
     targettop = max(0, target.to_window(0, target.y)[1]) if target else 0
 AttributeError: 'Screen' object has no attribute 'to_window'
```

ВОПРОС: Почему так происходит и как это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне помогла полная переустановка.
Только в этот раз я ставил
 kivy как на виртуальную машину

Comment: Полная переустановка чего (Kivy, Python, операционной системы)? Спасибо.

Comment: на тот момент я только установил Ubuntu и по глупости сделал "sudo apt-get remove python3"  после чего просто переустановил  Ubuntu и устанавливал на встроенный интерпретатор как на виртуальную машину